# Talend How to read multiple refcursors returned from Oracle sp

Tags: talend

I have called an Oracle Stored Procedure which is returning 7 refcursors in Talend Open Studio 5.3.

I want to read all the refcursors and create a single XML file.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I have called the oracle sp and took the resultsets in a tparserecordset_01.  After that I connected tparserecordset_01 with T_MAP. Then I created 7 tparserecordset(T02-T08) and connected the previous Tmap with these tparserecordsets. .Now I want to merge all the outputs and generate an XML which I am not able to do. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working. I have linked the t_parserecordset with t_Oraclesp and then I flowed all the cursors in a t_main component. After that I have created a t_parserecordset for each cursor with input link from t_main component and read the columns.

Now it is working fine.